# Private Git Repository Using a VPN with Tinc, SSH, and Git

Tags: ssh, vpn, git, repository

Would it be possible to set up a VPN using tinc as the VPN software on Ubuntu or Windows 7, and then connect from a computer (from outside the local network) to the computer hosting the VPN, in order to interact with a Git repository hosted on the VPN computer?

[image]

Comment: Yes, I believe that is the kind of setup I am looking for. Thanks for shortening my answer, also. Do you know if that kind of setup would be possible without forwarding ports?

Comment: I embedded the image, so it's easier to understand for others. You don't need port forwarding if you connect to the VPN, as your machine will then act as if it was *within* the LAN.

Comment: Does a VPN require port forwarding?

Comment: Well, depends on which VPN you want to set up, where you want it and what equipment you have in your LAN. Can you [edit] your question and supply some additional information? (For example, which operating systems involved, which router you would use, if your VPN hosting machine *is* the router/firewall, et cetera).

Comment: The software running the VPN would be tinc probably, and I suppose the operating system running the VPN would be either Windows 7 or Ubuntu most likely. The router I am using is a Cisco Valet Plus wireless router.

Comment: What's the question here? "Is it possible?" Well, as long as you can connect to the other computer, you can use a remote Git repo...

Comment: I am just mostly curious about setting up a VPN without port forwarding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kevin, it should be totally possible to do what you're describing, assuming that at least one side of the VPN has the ability to forward ports in. If both VPN endpoints are behind [one-to-many NATs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) then you're going to need something more than merely tinc.

If, however, you can forward ports in on one of your endpoints then you're in luck. Here's a write up that I put together explaining [how to get tinc working on Ubuntu, Windows 7 and Centos](http://wiki.cementhorizon.com/display/CH/How+to+install+and+configure+tinc+on+Windows+7+and+Ubuntu+10.10+Linux+and+CentOS+5). This covers all of the tinc setup but not how to establish port forwarding.

Once you have tinc setup and working on both ends, you'd simply make your git calls to the VPN network IP (something like 172.20.20.100 in my examples) :

```
git clone git@172.20.20.100:reponame.git
```

Comment: Unfortunately, forwarding ports is not an option for me. However, you still answered my question accurately and cleared up my confusion about how such a networking setup would work. Thank you.